# How to change sort order of a large amount of database records

Tags: database, data-structures

Say you have 1,000,000 db records.

Say each item has an order, 1->1,000,000.

Say I want to move item 2 to 823,423.

This means each item between 2 and 823,423 needs to be decrimented by 1, to maintain order and be unique.

This seems a pretty intensive task.

What solutions are there to this? Linked list in a database? Non unique priority record?

Answer (score 0):

Databases do not store records in sorted order.  A database uses an `index` to maintain sort order.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index

Comment: Yes, so you could use an index to make sure the order was accessible in a fast way, but that doesn't help the fact of needing to update a lot of rows?